# Seal report integration with asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, report, integration, seal

I want to show seal reports with in my asp.net application, For this i have integration TestandSample application code.
How can i execute report and render report with in my application.
what scripting file do i required and how to change the header footer as well.
My Current status is:

```
public ActionResult ReportResult()
        {
            //Simple load and report execution and generation in a HTML Result file
            Repository repository = Repository.Create();
            Report report = Report.LoadFromFile(@"C:\ProgramData\Seal Report Repository\Reports\Search - Orders.srex", repository);
            ReportExecution execution = new ReportExecution() { Report = report };
            execution.Execute();
            while (report.IsExecuting) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            string result = execution.GenerateHTMLResult();
            Process.Start(result);
            return View();    // How to return ---> execution.GenerateHTMLResult(); as view.
        }
```